# Example of inverse does not equal the argument

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, inverse

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$. For all subsets $N$ of $A$ it follows that

$N\subseteq f^{-1}(f(N))$

Problem: Show an example that $f^{-1}(f(N))$ does not necessarily equal  $N$

My idea: Would it be sufficient to let $A=\left \{ 0,1 \right \}$ and $B=\left \{  0\right \}$ and then be done? The inverse notation on a set is kind of messing with me.

Comment: You’re not done until you specify $f$ and $N$. Granted, there **is** only one function from $A$ to $B$, but you really do have to specify it, and you definitely have to specify $N$ and demonstrate that $f^{-1}[f[N]]$ really isn’t equal to $N$. ($M$ in the first line should be $A$.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott fixed to be "of $A$".

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Would $f(x)=x^2$ in the interval $\left (0,1  \right )$ work and choosing $N=1$ (or $x=1$)

Comment: That makes no sense: the interval $(0,1)$ isn’t even part of the domain $A$. Don’t look for an equation: $0$ and $1$ are the only elements of $A$, so you can specify $f$ by telling us what $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are.

Comment: Well if we specify $f$ to be $f(x)=x^2$ then $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1=f(-1)=1$ ?

Comment: Since $B=\{0\}$, and $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$, it is absolutely impossible for $f(1)$ to be $1$: $1$ is not in $B$. And since the domain $A$ has only two elements, there’s no reason to look for an equation for $f$; just say what $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are.

Comment: My idea was to define the two sets. But if we continue with that; $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=0$ if the  sets are defined as so.

Comment: and then the inverse of $f(N)$ would just be equal to the set $A$?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct as long as $N\ne\varnothing$. So how can you specify $N$ as a subset of $A$ so that $f^{-1}[f[N]]$ is not equal to $N$?

Comment: Just to pick it as an element in $A$ since it will return the value $f(N)=B$ and then $f^{-1}(f(N))=A$ which is definetly not equal to $N$ ?

Comment: Right: take $N$ to be either $\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$, and you’re in business.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks a lot. It is done! I have this speciel one: Let $Q$ be the following subset of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$:

$Q=\left \{ (a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}: b\neq 0 \right \}$

Define the relation $\sim $ on $Q$ as

$(a,b)\sim (c,d)\Leftrightarrow ad=bc$

Proof that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, and specify $[(2,3)]$ and more generally the equivalence class $[(a,b)]$. Try to give an explanation of $Q/\sim $. I have proved the equivalence but do not know how to specify the class and the general case. How would one do that?

Comment: I’m pretty sure that this question has been asked a number of times here, but here’s a hint: if $b\ne 0\ne d$, then $ad=bc$ if and only if $\frac{a}b=\frac{c}d$.